# Scrape links into pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, runtime-error

I am fairly new to this and I am facing issues all around. Any help/guidance is really appreciated!
I have a dataframe in the following structure:

```
data:
  LINK
<link_one>
<link_two>
<link_three>
```

The dataframe name is ***data*** and it has one column called ***LINK*** which contains few weblinks. 
I am trying to take each link from the column ***LINK*** and do some scraping to return text body contents of each link and attached it to a column called ***CONTENT*** in the dataframe. 
Here is what the outcome I am hoping for:

```
data:
  LINK            CONTENT
<link_one>     <text_body_one>
<link_two>     <text_body_two>
<link_three>   <text_body_three>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

data = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/links.csv")

def body_content(val):
    url = val
    try:
        page = requests.get(url, verify=False).text
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        pass 

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    p_tags = soup.find_all('p')
    p_tags_text = [tag.get_text().strip() for tag in p_tags]

    sentence_list = [sentence for sentence in p_tags_text if not '\n' in sentence]
    sentence_list = [sentence for sentence in sentence_list if '.' in sentence]
    article = ' '.join(sentence_list)
    return article

data['CONTENT'] = zip(*data['LINK'].map(body_content))
```

While the function ***body_content*** works but I can not get the contents to attach properly to the dataframe. Getting the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'page' referenced before assignment
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is because in the try/except part, the code goes to the except and thus doesn't create the variable page, you can do as following:

```
except requests.ConnectionError:
    return ''
```

So if it has a connection error, it will return an empty string.